# Deleting all but specified sheets in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to delete all sheets except for specifically named ones (INPUT, Template, Summary). Very new to JS so I am sure it's way off:

```
//Delete sheets that are not named 'Input', 'Template', and 'Summary'
function deleteRedundantSheets() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

for (i = 0; i <= sheets.length; i++) {
  switch(sheets[i]) {
   case sheet.getSheetName() === "INPUT":
     break;
   case sheet.getSheetName() === "Template":
     break;
   case sheet.getSheetName() === "SUMMARY":
    break;
   default:
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet[i]);
    ss.deleteActiveSheet;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Once you have assigned the `ActiveSpreadSheet` to a variable, you can use that reference. In your code `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();` can be replaced with `var sheets = ss.getSheets();` as variable `ss` contains the reference to the active spreadsheet.
2. [`getSheets`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets%28%29) returns an array of sheets. So when you write `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`, you are actually assigning the first element of the array in variable `sheet`. Hence in your `case` statements, you are always referring to the same sheet. So instead of using `sheet.getSheetName() === "INPUT"`, you should use `sheets[i].getSheetName() === "INPUT"`
3. To delete a sheet, you can also use the [`deleteSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet%28Sheet%29) function. This was added recently in Google Scripts.

Below is a modified code that you could use (I have not tested this, but you should get the idea).

```
function deleteRedundantSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "INPUT":
     case "Template":
     case "SUMMARY":
         break;
     default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. I was getting error with your code but al I had to do was change line 3 to this:

Comment: var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];

Comment: Naah, don't do that... that way you are just referring to the first sheet... and if you use `Browser.msgBox(sheets.length);` before the for loop, you'll see the value is undefined. The error was because if the **<=** sign in the for loop. Change it to **<**

Comment: because we start with i = 0, so if use `<=` we are actually counting more than the number of elements in array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DeleteNewSheets(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var allowedSheetNames = ["My Stupid Sheet1", "Sheet 2"];

  for (var i = sheets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();

    if (!allowedSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
  }
}
```

Do a Trigger on DeleteNewSheets() onchange, it will delete all sheets except those two. Simple.